# Android video playing issues

Tags: android, html, http, webview

I have a HTML5 webapp with videos, stored in internal memory.

If I open the webapp in a WebView from the internal memory, the video doesn't play with a message: "Sorry, this video is not playable".

However if I copy the webapp to a server and open it via http, video plays fine.

I also tried to play the video in a VideoView, but the same happens like above:
From internal memory it doesn't play, however if opened via http from a website it works just fine.

Any workarounds? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled javascript and other plugins to your webview?

```
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Of course, both two property is true in my project, and the embedded video is plays correctly form the web. Seems this is a file opening bug.. Or not? I dont understand.

Comment: maybe you should add some code so that we dont duplicate suggestions

Comment: Finally the problem is solved. This is a file acces problem, a simple chmod helps.